# Find the right font

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec, texstudio

What must be done to find the right font with these commands?

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Ubuntu}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Ubuntu Medium}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text]{Ubuntu Mono}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % line spacing
```

I am in use of Ubuntu Linux and I do believe to already have installed the correct fonts. I do get a whole list of fonts using the command `fc-list | grep "Ubuntu"` (Screenshot 1). The editor I use is TexStudio and I installed all the texlive-packets `sudo apt install texlive*`.

[image]

Compiling the tex-document with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX results in errors within the TexStudio GUI (Screenshot 2). The errors are about the same with both configurations (Screenshot 3).

[image]

[image]

- `xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`
- `lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

I believe that the error is due to not finding the correct font. Am I right with the assumption? What steps are necessary to solve this issue? Are there still packets that need to be installed in Ubuntu?

Comment: If you look at the error message you see that it complains specifically about "Ubuntu Medium". The red highlighting is therefore a bit misleading, the error actually appears in the `\setsansfont` line and not in the `\setmonofont` line. Also in your list of fonts you see that `Ubuntu` and `Ubuntu Mono` are present, but not `Ubuntu Medium`. Based on the name I would expect that you should look for some Ubuntu package for this font and not for a TeXLive package.

Comment: Never post pictures of either code or errors. Instead, copy and paste as plain text into your posts. Images of code and images of errors cannot be read by those who depend on screen readers and cannot be found by users searching the site or web for the same issue.

Comment: Note that you may need different code to find the font when using different engines. In any case, I doubt `Ubuntu Medium` is correct. What are you aiming for here? If you don't want to use a serif font, just set Ubuntu as the sans font and change the default font family to sans. (But be aware that maths will still use serif as normal regardless.)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much guys and thank you for mentioning that the error message by TexStudio is misleading. Changing the font to Tahoma worked. Changing anyone of them to `Ubuntu` results in `xdvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1 (0) No output PDF file written.`. But using `Tahoma` does the trick for me. Found the correct name using `fc-list | awk -F: '{print $2}'`. For context, this tex-document is from my Master's Thesis back in 2018 and it used to work back then. I cannot wrap my head around why `Ubuntu` or `Ubuntu Medium` are unavailable to `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont` and `\setmonofont`.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for letting me know to better copy and paste code segments instead of images where possible. I adapted the post a bit to fit that goal.

Comment: Note there's no problem using `Ubuntu` or `Ubuntu Mono` provided you have the latter installed. It's only `Ubuntu Medium` which generates the error.

Comment: As for the error message mentioned in the post you are correct that only `Ubuntu Medium` is shown as an error. But when I change the other ones to `Ubuntu` I get the mentioned `Invalid font` errors.